# How to show ratings from web service in the ratings bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-json

I am using JSON web service and I want to show the ratings which are coming from the web service,  in the ratings bar.

But I have no idea how to deal with this. I am only getting examples for the hard coded ratings.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which format you are getting the rating, can you share the response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting the rating from web service in the `String format`, so for displaying the Rating in the RatingBar you need to convert it into the `Float data type`

```
Float ratingFromServer = Float.valueOf(mResponse.getRating());// this is the rating you are getting from server
```

and for setting the Rating in the RatingBar you need to add the below code

```
mRatingBar.setRating(ratingFromServer);//setting the rating in ratingBar
```

Try this and do let me know if this helped you.